# MySQL fulltext search 1 character works with MyISAM only?

Tags: mysql, magento, full-text-search, innodb, myisam

I have a query which should return 1 result

```
SELECT * FROM 
    `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1` AS `search_index`
WHERE
    (MATCH (data_index) AGAINST ('+Product +Set +b' IN BOOLEAN MODE));
```

If the table engine is MyISAM, it works.
But if I change the table back to innodb, it returns nothing.
The problem is caused by searching `+b`

I used `show variables like 'ft_min%'` to check the value is 1.

As the system is Magento 2.1, I am no idea is there any problem if I change the default engine. How can I get the result if the search condition include 1 character in innodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ft_min_word_len` is for MyISAM;
`innodb_ft_min_token_size` is for InnoDB.

When changing the setting, be sure to rebuild any FULLTEXT indexes.  Use `OPTIMIZE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks. I updated `innodb_ft_min_token_size` to 1 and reboot the database. Then `ALTER TABLE abc ENGINE='InnoDB';`, but still not work in InnoDB

Comment: I used `show variables` to check `innodb_ft_min_token_size` = 1

Comment: Do more than half the rows have the word 'b' in them?